# showing identity element in a vector space

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I want to show identity element of a normed vector space with 1 that have extra line .How can I do it?

Comment: In order for your question to not get closed as being unclear. Please explain in more detail what you are looking for. As the question is here is is hard to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @Sigur - Which math font package provides usable output for `\mathbb{1}`?

Comment: @Mico, sorry. I mean `ds` as you wrote. It was out of habit. lol

Comment: Normed vector space don't have a 1. Normed algebras may.

Answer (score 0):

If by "1 that have extra line" you mean a double-struck `1`, the following solution may be of interest to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
$\mathds{1}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me.